# Vimeo - thumbnails for private videos

Tags: php, video, thumbnails, private, vimeo

I need to get a thumbnail image of a Vimeo video with following privacy settings:

- only people with private link can watch
- video can be embedded only on specific domains

I tried oembed:

```
function grab_vimeo_thumbnail($vimeo_url){
    if( !$vimeo_url ) return false;
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' . $vimeo_url ) );
    if( !$data ) return false;
    return $data->thumbnail_url;}
```

But it only works if privacy is set to "Anyone can watch". There is not "thumbnail_url" argument available when I set required privacy restrictions as I need.

Some ideas how to do it? Thanks

Comment: So you're asking how to bypass a security feature?

Answer (score 0):

For a video with unlisted privacy, you must use the full URL with oembed:

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/[video_id]/[unlisted_hash]
```

For a video with domain-level embed privacy, you must include a Referer header (as documented [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos#embedding-videos-with-domain-privacy)). Expressed as a curl:

```
curl -e http://example.com https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https:%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2F286898202
```

Comment: ok, that is nice, but how do you do this without curl?